# validate input value contain x numbers of numeric characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I need to validate a input field which should contain at least x number of numeric characters.

eg: let say I need to input value has at least 5 numeric characters

```
12345 - valid
AB12345 - valid
123456 - valid
AB312312 - valid
asd - not valid
213 - not valid
```

First I tried with `input.length`, but I don't know it will have a leading letters or not, so `length` doesn't help for me

how should I do this validation with jquery or javascript ?

Comment: Another alternative is to replace all digits with nothing (i.e. remove all digits), and then compare the length of the original and new strings. That would tell you how many digits you extracted (and hence how many were there to begin with).

Comment: Remove all non digits `.replace(/\D+/g, '')` and then check the `length` of the string.

Comment: @Tushar that what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say you are looking at validating 5 numeric then you can use regular expression `/(?=(?:[\d]){5})`.

What this expression does is that;

1. `(?=)` means start looking ahead
2. `(?:[\d])` means match digits but don't capture them
3. `{5}` means `(?:[\d])` (match digit) do 5 times

```js
"use strict";
let numbers = [ '12345', 'ABC12345', '123456', 'AB312312', 'asd', '213'];

numbers.forEach(number=> {
    if (/(?=(?:[\d]){5})/.exec(number)) {
        console.log(number + " is valid.");
    };
});
```

Comment: @JanithCinthana let me know if this works for you. Happy to discuss further.

Comment: Tip: (for now) avoid using new JS constructs like `let`, `arrow functions` - browser support for this is not good. Even `array.prototype.forEach` is useless in < IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions will do the trick

```
function check(str,x){
   var pattern = '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]{'+x+'}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$';
   if(str.match(pattern)) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: That would look at the whole length of the input and not only number of digits, isn't it?

Comment: True. Wait let me think about a different solution

Comment: Good for you. You could also use my function where `str` is the string and `x` is the minimum number of occurences it should have

Comment: Not me but the one that initially posted the question.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I thought the one that posted the question commented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120572/discussion-between-jay-ghosh-and-fdavidov).

Answer (score 1):

If

```
inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length < 5
```

then input field is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this

```
x = 5;
myString = "AB12345";
if (myString.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length >= x) {
    alert('valid');
} else {
    alert('not valid');
}
```

see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fewr88o9/2/).